# How to move a windows license from a virtual machine to a real machine

Tags: windows, windows-7, virtualization, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I would like to move the Windows 7 license that I've installed on a virtual machine to a real machine. Of course, deactivating the virtual machine.

Is it possible? If yes, how can I do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an OEM licence as in it was on your pc when you bought it, legally no, although it is possible, if you phoned up Microsoft and told them your motherboard had died and you had to have it replaced with another that's why you need to re activate your OEM licence it would work, if that was what happened, but its not legit if your motherboard didn't die, but its probably more legit that cracking it, that certainly isn't legal. If its a licence you bought by itself, just install it on the second pc, when you activate it, it will de active the other one. By the way, I take it you have the licence key ?, if you do just install it on the other one and type it in.
Another option is to just image the virtual machine over the top of the physical machine, e.g take a copy of it with something like clonezilla, then restore the disk image to the physical machine, this will most probably deactivate the key, but just re activate it when it prompts you using the usual activation method.

Comment: It's not an OEM license. So, if what you said is true, I could install Windows 7 on another machine using the same license number. After the installation the previous copy should be no longer valid, instead the copy installed on the real machine should be valid. Am I right?

Comment: Yes that's correct, once you active the second machine, it will de active the other one, its only the OEM licences that are fixed to one machine.

Comment: By the way, remember to activate the second copy, this will then transfer it over, just go to system, then to windows activation. Windows will still work on the virtual pc after this, its just you will get a nag message saying to activate it, don't click this though or you will transfer it back again, you can only do this transfer I think its either 3 or 5 times so don't do it too many times otherwise you will have to ring up Microsoft to ask for some more activations.

Comment: I just tried this with Windows 8 and it didn't work. The second install wouldn't accept the Product Key.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the license key is you can use slmgr command line utility that comes with windows to change the license key on the new machine and deactivate it on the old machine.